# Did Moses Have A Speech Impediment?

Tags: bible, acts, exodus, moses

Did Moses have a speech impediment?  Because Acts 7:22 says he was powerful in speech and action which contradicts Exodus 4:10.

> Acts 7:22 And Moses was instructed in all the wisdom of the Egyptians, and he was mighty in his words and deeds.
>
> Exodus 4:10 But Moses said to the Lord, “Oh, my Lord, I am not eloquent, either in the past or since you have spoken to your servant, but I am slow of speech and of tongue.”

Answer (score 5):

Exodus 4:10 says that when God asked Moses to speak for him, Moses came up with the excuse that he was “slow of speech and tongue.”  Some Bible commentators have suggested that Moses might have suffered from some sort of speech impediment.  However, it’s more likely that Moses was simply resisting God because he was unwilling to return to Pharaoh’s court and stand up for the Hebrew slaves.

What we do know about Moses is that he was brought up as the adopted son of Pharaoh’s daughter and would have benefitted from the finest education.  That’s why Acts 7:22 says Moses was instructed “in all the wisdom of the Egyptians, and he was mighty in his words and deeds.”   That is not a contradiction of what Moses said in Exodus 4:10.  The events that led up to the exodus of the Hebrews out of Egypt testify to the fact that God used Moses and his brother in the outworking of His divine plans.  It was God who enabled Moses.  Moses’ feeble excuse that he was “slow of speech and tongue” didn’t work.  In spite of Moses’ failings, God saw fit to use him and to empower him.  Because God was with Moses then no impediment, real or imagined, would stand in God’s way.

Comment: Exodus 40 10-17  we see that God appointed Aaron as spokesman for Moses. Vs 14 God says “I know He Aaron can speak very well” obviously God knew that Moses did have some legit problem with speech like stuttering.

Comment: @Kris-good point, although God was not best pleased with Moses for trying to get out of the assignment (see Exodus 4:14), especially after he had assured Moses that he would help Moses to speak and teach him what to say (verse 11-12).  Moses seems to be complaining of not being eloquent or quick-witted enough to respond to the pharaoh.  Acts 7:22 says "Moses was powerful in speech and action."  Perhaps Moses was just scared?  Whatever, it seems Moses was unwilling to trust God which made God angry.  Lesson there for us all, yes?

Comment: @Kris Not being a good speaker does not necessarily mean a speech impediment. Indeed, "Aaron can speak very well" might imply that he is just speaking of competence or proficiency rather than 'he does not have a speech impediment.'

Answer (score -1):

Acts 7:22 when it says  "he was mighty in his words and deeds", means he was truthful when he spoke and his deeds we're great. Many contradictions in the Bible but these two passeges aren't one of them. Nabi Musa(alaihi salaam) didn't have a speech impediment, when he was a child he burnt his tounge on a  hot peace of coal. A test from the Pharaoh to see if he could tell the difference between a bowl of hot coals and a bowl of jewels and gold after grabbing the Pharaoh's beard and smacking him in the face. when he began to reach for the jewels and gold Angel Jibreel guided Musa (peace be upon him) hand to the bowl of  hot coals. Afterwards putting it into his mouth and burning his own tounge. The Pharaoh spared Musa's life thinking if he couldn't tell the difference between hot coals and jewels then he was no threat to the Pharaoh himself

Comment: Looks like the story is attested in both [Islam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_in_Islam#Test_of_prophecy) and [Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13453/moshe-and-the-red-hot-coals).  Do you have any idea how old the story was?  Do you think Luke, the author of Acts knew about this story?